# RSpec - Functional Test - Syntax Check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

so I'm writing a Test for my UserController, and the associated Devise dependency.

I'm trying to write a test that verify's userA can't access the show page of userB, but is redirected to the root_path instead. I'm guessing syntax errors are my issue, but I'd love another pair of eyes on it!

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe UsersController, :type => :controller do 

  # create test user
    before do
        @userA = User.create!(email: "test@example.com", password: "1234567890")
        @userB = User.create!(email: "test2@example.com", password: "1234567890")
    end

    describe "GET #show" do
        before do
            sign_in(@userA)
        end

        context "Loads correct user details" do
            get :show
            expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
            expect(assigns(:user)).to eq @userA
        end

        context "No user is logged in" do 
            it "redirects to login" do
                get :show, id: @userA.id
                expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
            end
        end
    end

    describe "GET Unauthorized page" do
        before do
            sign_in(@userA)
        end

        context "Attempt to access show page of UserB" do
            it "redirects to login" do 
                get :show, id: @userB.id
                expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
                expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: I already added in the needed devise config code into rails_helper.rb

Comment: What does the output have?  Just that it failed?  Which one of them failed?

Comment: I don't get any failures, which is what's making me suspicious actually. 
Output :
  <code>
  [webapp (master)]bundle exec rspec spec/controllers
  ..

  Finished in 0.09632 seconds (files took 6.2 seconds to load)
  2 examples, 0 failures
  </code>

Comment: sorry for noob reply @j-dexx

Comment: On a side note - use `let` and `let!` instead of instance vars in your tests. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Comment: cheers @max! I'll get into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an "it" block in

```
    context "Loads correct user details" do
        get :show
        expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
        expect(assigns(:user)).to eq @userA
    end
```

Comment: Ah darn! Thanks mate!

Comment: Test is still passing so I'm guessing the rest of my logic must be right!

Comment: cool, on a side note, you should try not to use real db objects in your controller tests... Have you tried to use factory_girl or something like that?

Comment: Learning about it right as a matter of fact! Thank you for the advice!